# WordPress multisite and 301 redirect for a specific domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

The domain of main site of my WordPress multisite is :

```
mainsite.fr
```

I've two other subsites with their own domain name:

```
subsite1.fr
subsite2.fr
```

I need to redirect all pages of the main site to another external site (`thirdsite.fr`)

If I write in `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://thirdsite.fr
```

I don't have access to the subsite and the admin of the multisite.

What do I have to write in the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to redirect all pages of the main site to another external site (thirdsite.fr)

You should be using `mod_rewrite` rule for as this as your **topmost** rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mainsite\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://thirdsite%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# remaining rules come below this line
```

Make sure this new rule is your topmost rule in site root .htaccess and you clear your browser cache before testing this change.